# Input checkbox value that is created dynamically into MySQL if checked

Tags: php

I am pulling in questions from a questions table in MySQL and populating them in a form. This works fine and I am populating checkboxes as well that the value is populated with the QuestionID. The array is properly populating but I want to take the value of the checked checkboxes (which is my question ID) and insert that ID into a table, so that I have the questions that are selceted for use by their ID. Here is what I have so far:

```
//Declare the QuestionID as a array
$QuestionID = array();


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
echo '<div id="QuestionSelection"><input id="chkQuestion" type="checkbox" value=" '.$row['QuestionID'].'" name=chkQuestion align="left"/><p>' . $row['Question'] .'</p></div><br/><br/>';

//Assign the QuestionID from the table to the var
$QuestionID[] = $row['QuestionID'];

}


if($_POST['submitted']) { 


if (isset($_POST['chkQuestion']))
{
//create the query for the score
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO tbl_QuestionSelected (`QuestionID`) VALUES ($QuestionID)"; 

//Run the query 
$run2 = @mysqli_query ($conn,$sql2);

//Confirm message data was entered with a correct response and a graphic
echo '<h1>Submitted!!</h1>';

}


}//End of IF 'submitted
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to insert multiple records in one statement is what I'm understanding.

```
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO `tbl_QuestionSelected` (`QuestionID`) VALUES(". implode('),(', $QuestionID) . ")";
```

This will join each index inside `$QuestionID` with `),(`

If you were to echo `$sql2` you would get

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_QuestionSelected` (`QuestionID`) VALUES(1),(2),(3)
```

Comment: So everything else is right the issue why its not submitting any info into my table is my SQL statement?

Comment: Don't suppress the error on the execution, perhaps there's an error before hand. Perhaps it isn't even reaching the if statement.

Comment: Yes I will have multiple inserts based on how many checkboxes are checked and it will need to insert the id that is set as the value of the checkbox associated with the question

Comment: I answered that for you, do you have a second question?

Comment: It's getting to my insert statement because if I hardcode the value to 1 it will insert into the table but as the hardcoded ID(obviously) and only for 1 checkbox not if I pick multiples

Comment: you method is inserting values but right now I have 3 questions and no matter which checkbox I pick i\or how many you method inserts the value for all 3 and only once

Comment: That's a problem with your while loop. You're looping through every result and appending it to the array, thus they will all be added at once.

Comment: well i want them all added to the array and themn the array assigns the value. then based on what is selected it will insert just that ID if the second and third are selected it would insert the 2nd and third ID etc

Answer (score 0):

try to loop your ids and escape it!!

```
    $ids_list = '';
    foreach($_POST["chkQuestion"] as $id)
    {
        $ids_list .= (strlen($ids_list) > 0 ? ',' : '').mysql_real_escape_string($id);
    }

    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO tbl_QuestionSelected (`QuestionID`) VALUES (".$ids_list.")";
```

Comment: sorry, use your Post array `$_POST["chkQuestion"]`

Comment: this may be a stupid question but isn't that what foreach($_POST["chkQuestion"] as $id) does? its looping each array?

Comment: my response wasn't meant rude that your reply wasn't working I was just looking for input as to possibly why.Sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop to get the questions that are checked.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_POST["chkQuestion"]);$i++) {
  "INSERT INTO tbl_QuestionSelected (QuestionID) VALUES('".$_POST["chkQuestion"][$i]."');
}
```

This way the MySQL statement has the actual values to insert into your table.

Answer (score 0):

This will assign the value based on the array for the value and insert it into MySQL:

```
//Declare the QuestionID as a array
$QuestionID = array();


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
echo '<div id="QuestionSelection"><input id="chkQuestion" type="checkbox" value=" '.$row['QuestionID'].'" name="QuestionID[' . $row['QuestionID'] . ']">' .$row['Question']. '</p></div><br/><br/>';

//Assign the QuestionID from the table to the var
$QuestionID[] = $row['QuestionID'];

}

if($_POST['submitted']) { 


$ids_list = '';

foreach($_POST["QuestionID"] as $key=>$value) {
{
$ids_list .= (strlen($ids_list) > 0 ? ',' : '').mysql_real_escape_string($value);
}

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO tbl_QuestionSelected (`QuestionID`) VALUES (".$ids_list.")";

//Run the query 
$run2 = @mysqli_query ($conn,$sql2);


}//End of IF 'submitted
}
```